# Missing Wifi Adapter on old Mac

Tags: wireless, macbook

I'm new to linux and I installed 18.10 on a old 2008 macbook and when I checked for a Wifi signal, it didn't see one. when I checked in Wireless, it said that there was no Wifi Adapter. is there a way to find how to install or find the built-in wifi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [2008 Macbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_(2006%E2%80%932012)) is either the MB402*/A MB403*/A MB404*/A (MacBook4,1) or MB402*/B (MacBook4,2), both of which use the Integrated Airport Extreme 802.11a/b/g/n (draft-n enabled) which uses a Broadcom proprietary driver. If you can make a wired connection, you can follow the instructions at [MacBook can’t find WiFi for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076964/macbook-can-t-find-wifi-for-ubuntu-18-04) to load the relevant proprietary drivers.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to load the drivers without having to go back to the installer disk like in the link you sent?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, though the install disk should be downloadable from the Linksys web site. Remember: 32 bit only.

Comment: My fault, I didn't know how to get to the software & updates until getting a good look at it. it worked, thanks.